# C++ inheritance: Templates Vs Pointers

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, inheritance

I am trying to understand what is the best solution between pointers and templates in a inheritance scenario.

Consider the following classes.

```
class Event
{
};

class Filter
{
    public:
        virtual void process(Event *event) = 0;
};

class Pipeline
{
    private:
        std::vector<Filter*> _filters
};
```

Each user can expand the Event class and the Filter class to hold actual data and actual filtering functions. The pipeline class only connects the filters together with queues and executes the method process.

UP until now I always used pointers to deal with inheritance, e.g. a std::vector of Filter pointers and a process function that receives an Event pointer. Instead of pointers can template be used?

For example

```
class Event
{
};

template<class Event> class Filter
{
    public:
        virtual void process(Event *event) = 0;
};

template<class Filer> class Pipeline
{
    private:
        std::vector<Filter> _filters
};
```

Does this work, is even possible and what are the main implications?

I have another example to discuss.
Consider the following code:

```
template<class Element, class Cluster>
Cluster* closestCluster(Element *e, std::vector<Cluster*> &clusters)
{
    double minDist = clusters[0]->distance(e);
    Cluster *c = clusters[0];
    for(std::size_t i = 1 ; i < clusters.size(); ++i)
    {
         double tmp = clusters[i]->distance(e);
         if(tmp < minDist)
         {
             minDist = tmp;
             c=clusters[i];
         }
    }
    return c;
}

Cluster* closestCluster(Element *e, std::vector<Cluster*> & clusters)
{
    double minDist = clusters[0]->distance(e);
    Cluster *c = clusters[0];
    for(std::size_t i = 1 ; i < clusters.size(); ++i)
    {
        double tmp = clusters[i]->distance(e);
        if(tmp < minDist)
        {
            minDist = tmp;
            c=clusters[i];
        }
     }
     return c;
}
```

At first glance I look at this to functions and though there is no big difference.
But in my code only the first one works. Because my array of clusters is of this type:

```
std::vector<KMedoidCluster*> &clusters
```

I thought the compiler could understand that KMedoidclsuter is a extension of the base class Cluster. But apparently it does not work, so in order to get some flexibility I had to use templates.

Comment: `std::vector<Filter>` and the fact that `Filter` has virtual functions do not play well together.

Comment: So std::vector<Filter*> is a better option?

Comment: I am just trying to grasp the advantages of templates and when to use it

Answer (score 3):

In essence you are trading run-time polymorphism for compile-time polymorphism.

What this means is that with the second approach, a pipeline can only consist of a single type of filter, and that type must be known at compile time. The first approach is more flexible than that.

On the other hand, memory management is simpler in the second approach. However, you could use smart pointers with the first approach to simplify things.

Additionally, the second approach could potentially be more performant. Whether this is relevant is a different question.

In a nutshell, I'd use the first approach but would use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: In this specific class I am interested in flexibility.

Comment: Normally I use normal pointer, is a habit of programing in plain old C. So there is no clear right answer is depends on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First I think use template will work.but your code may write like this:

```
class Event
{
};

template<class T1> class Filter
{
    public:
        virtual void process(T1 *event) = 0;
};

 template<class T2> class Pipeline
{
    private:
        std::vector<T2> _filters
};
```

The main advantage of using template is that, you can set you class T1 not only Event but also other class like Event1. And you can set T2 as Filter or other class Filter1.

However in this condition,  this becomes a disadvantage. You can not make sure about your Filter class can always process object of class Event. Other class such as Event1's object will also work.

Finally, I suggest you use the pointers not the template in this condition.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: When class is used inside the template definition is not mandatory to give the name of the base class?

Comment: A template name is totally a virtual name, just a id. So you can not give the name of the base class.

Comment: So how can I guarantee that the object is an extension of the a certain base class?

Comment: You just write like this : BaseClass *base_class.

Comment: Can you give me some example?

Comment: In you example code, are you sure you have include all Clauter and Element definition in you code ?

Comment: That classes have more code than the example. Is it helpful to add the rest?

Comment: I think you can write like this:
    std::vector<Cluster *> test_vec;
    KMediaCluster test_kmedia_cluster;
    test_vec.push_back(&test_kmedia_cluster);
    closetCluster(test_element, test_vec);